# Latex command \bar not working properly in Python docstring

Tags: python, latex, docstring

I have a function with a docstring as follows,

```
def func(x):

    '''Boring function

    Notes
    -----
    Let :math:`\bar{x}_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k}x_{ik}`,
    '''

    return x
```

But the `\bar` command in Latex renders as "ar",

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is interpreting the backslashes. You need to pass the backslashes through so LaTeX can interpret them; you should use a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) to do so:

```
def func(x):

    # Note the r!
    r'''Boring function

    Notes
    -----
    Let :math:`\bar{x}_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k}x_{ik}`,
    '''
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer for future visitors: use two backslashes instead of one. It's useful for formatting formulas as we saw above, but also for uses like:

```
print("/!\\ Error encountered.")
```